# is there any other library the works like bios.h in Visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

is there any other library the works like bios.h in Visual studio 2008 this header is present in TC a very older version but i need some functionality of it in visual studio 2008 can some guide be about this

i need .net independent libs.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does bios.h do ?
You can't access the bios routines from windows>98

EDIT:
Using the serial port in windows from C is similar to using any other file (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx) if you need detailed low level control of individual CTRL lines it's a bit trickier but still doable.

Comment: actually i have to configure serial port and transmit data on it bios.h provides me this functionality i had coded it year ago in TC when i m a student know i want to use that code but VS has no bios.h file if there is any other solution then tell me.\

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a serial port and transmitting data over it is built into the .NET framework.  Check out the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class documentation, there are some examples to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx